# Php calculatons on money to precision of .01 cent

Tags: php

I'm building a platform in PHP for a client that requires calculations, in particular division, to be done on money. These calculations need to be done to an accuracy of .01 cent. Is the correct way to multiple the currency by 10000 and cast to an INT, then do calcultions on this number?

Comment: [use the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and take the absolute values in the calculations and test if they are within a given range. Otherwise, multiply by whatever number you like and cast to int, but be ***very careful*** with division and rounding.

Comment: When you say be very careful, do you mean always check after calculations that results are in a given range? If so, what range should this be?

Comment: Why has this been down-voted? This question is about working with a precision of .01 cent, I've searched other answers and they do not elaborate on anything less than 1 cent.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest do all your calculations in the correct/actual floating numbers (Don't CAST or convert them) and you can just format it later with 2 decimal precisions.

Use **number_format** or **round** for displaying results only.

Comment: Im trying to avoid problems with doing calculations with floats - tends to be unreliable

Comment: Can you elaborate how it's unreliable?
If you are working on all float numbers or "decimal/currency" if its from db, and the variables are all same it should reliable enough for 0.01 in your case.

Comment: @fedmich Floats are unfortunately not reliable. Some numbers cannot be stored exactly in a float. The PHP docs cites: `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` as an example which on most systems will return 7 rather than 8.

Comment: Thanks Jim for explaining, but shouldnt it be floatval((0.1+0.7)*10); to be accurate?

Comment: Anyways, I understand what you and him meant. Thank you still; he just have to be **very careful** alright.